# Explanation of the isolated singularities

Tags: complex-analysis

> We have $f: D \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, with $D = \mathbb{C}$ \ $( \{ x : x \leq 0 \} \cup \{ 1 \} \cup \{ ik : k \in \mathbb{Z} \})$, defined by
>
> $\displaystyle f(z) = \frac{ Log z}{(z-1)^2 sin(i \pi z) } + \frac{sin(\pi z)}{(z-1)^3}$, with $(z \in D)$
>
> Determine al types of the isolated singularities.

The answer is given. Singularities appear in the zero points of the denominator, so in $1$ and $ik$ with $k \neq 0$. It says:

> For $z = 1$:

ord$(Log z ; 1) = 1$. Why?

ord$\displaystyle (\frac{ Log z}{(z-1)^2 sin(i \pi z) }; 1) = 1 - (2+0)$. The  $1$ is from above I guess , I understand the $2$, but where does the $0$ come from?

> The same problem I have with $z = ik$:

ord$\displaystyle (\frac{ Log z}{(z-1)^2 sin(i \pi z) }; ik) = 0  - (0+1)$. How is this obtained?

Briefly I only know that if we have the form $(z-a)^k \cdot f(z)$, then ord$(f;a) = -k$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The multiplicity of a zero of $f$ at $a$ is the number of vanishing coefficients in the Taylor expansion of $f$ around $z=a$:
$$
f(z) = f(a) + f'(a)(z-a) + \frac12 f''(a)(z-a)^2 + \cdots
$$
so the number of vanishing derivatives determines how large power of $(z-a)$ we can factor out. Hence, the order of a *holomorphic* function at $z=a$ is the multiplicity of its zero.

To handle *meromorphic* functions, i.e. quotients of holomorphic functions, you should check that (for $f, g$ holomorphic): $\operatorname{ord}(fg; a) = \operatorname{ord}(f;a) + \operatorname{ord}(g;a)$ and $\operatorname{ord}(f/g;a) = \operatorname{ord}(f;a) - \operatorname{ord}(g;a)$.

---

$\operatorname{Log}(z)$ has a simple zero at $z=1$, since its derivative $1/z$ is non-zero at $z=1$.

Similarly, $\sin(i\pi z)$ has order $0$ at $z=1$, since $\sin(i\pi) \neq 0$. (Compute it!)

For $z=ik$, the computations are similar.